# Varying interest charges on car loan

Tags: loans, car, interest

I am making my $386 a month car loan payments each month on time.  I just looked at the payment history and the amounts of principal and interest vary widely each month.

For example:

- October: Balance Change $313.12 and interest $69.88.
- September: $320.72 and interest $62.28.
- August: $339.30 and interest $43.70
- July: $303.29; Interest $79.71   and so it goes.

What is going on?  And is there anything I can do payment wise that would improve the cost of this loan as I don't want to be paying extra interest some months.    Thanks.

Comment: Is it a variable rate loan?

Comment: What was the original rate, amount and length of the loan?

Comment: Was the payment made on the same day each month? Or is there a "statement date" that varies?

Comment: The only thing that makes sense to me is if the July payment was made later in the month than the August payment, and some of the "August" interest was included in the July payment. Which would be unusual (most loans use a fixed amortization schedule), but would be a very slight benefit to the lender.